# Android app crash due to images

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, imageview

I am pretty new to android. I was writing a program to change the image on button click. Without the images, my app works perfectly. But with images, the app crashes.

SIZE of img - 4kb, 80 X 80 in dimension.

My code -

```
 protected void clickMe(View view){
    EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yo dudE "+name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.i("Phone : ", phone.getText().toString());

}
```

Stacktrace :

> 07-04 11:06:04.964 10037-10037/com.satyakisanyal.myfirstandroidproject
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                            Process: com.satyakisanyal.myfirstandroidproject, PID: 10037
>                                                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
>                                                                                                at
>   com.satyakisanyal.myfirstandroidproject.MainActivity.clickMe(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
>                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Reason of crash: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView`

Comment: Can you add the xml file?

Comment: show me your xml and put whole java file so i can change regarding your requirement, i wanted to know your onCreate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
```

It appears that id `img1` is of `RelativeLayout` out and not of an `ImageView`

Comment: Yeah... I was using a different id for my image... Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are casting  a `RelativeLayout` to `ImageView` in android. Check what is `R.id.img1` in xml file?

Comment: Yeah... I was using a different id for my image... Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Check the logcat, it is showing this error.
`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView`
Check the id of ImageView before using it.